# I wonder how to receive packets from nestjs

Tags: python, node.js, tcp, nestjs, packet

i want to read packet

i tryed nodejs

node js :

```js
const net = require("net"); // import net

// create the server
let server = net.createServer((connection) => {
  // run all of this when a client connects
  connection.on("data", (data) => {
    // run this when data is received
    const rev = data.toString()
    console.log(rev); // prints the data
  });
});

server.listen(50000, () => {
  console.log("waiting for a connection"); // prints on start
});

// console.log
// x00\x0000\x0006\x0001\x0Bb03TB\rdc\x0000\x0001\x0Bb8X\x0000\x0114\x0000\x0000\x0000\x0001\x0000\x0008\x0000%DB20000\fc8\x0000\x0118y\x0000\x0000\x0Bba\x0001\x0000\x0000\rdd\x0001\x0000\x0000\rd4\x0001\x0000\x0000\x0118y\x0000\x0000\x0115\x0003\x0000\x0000\t9a\x0000\x0000\x0000\t9a\x0000\x0000\x0000p\x0117\x0000\x0000,\x0000\x0000\x0000\n' +
```

packet sender :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVXLc.png)

at python try:

```py
class Server(asyncio.Protocol):
  ...
  def data_received(self, data)
  print(data)
  ...
main():
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  factory = loop.create_server(lambda: Server())

# print
# x00\x0000\x0006\x0001\x0Bb03TB\rdc\x0000\x0001\x0Bb8X\x0000\x0114\x0000\x0000\x0000\x0001\x0000\x0008\
```

nestjs : ???
i don't know....